# Check boolean expression in bash

Tags: bash

I'm having troubles with the following check against a boolean variable:

```
for i in "${list[@]}"
do
        if [ $i = "web.war" ] ; then
        $deployed = true; echo "Deployed!!!!!";
        fi
done

echo $deployed;
```

In this example, the condition $i = "web.war" is satisfied, in fact the text "**Deployed**" is printed. However the value of the variable $deployed is false when I print it in the last line. Is it a matter of variable scoping or what ?
Thanks

Comment: "`deployed = true`", note the lack of `$`.

Comment: Thanks, however without the "$" the output is "deployed: command not found"

Comment: I guess you're looking for `-eq`

Comment: Sorry, had Perl in my head. You _also_ need to remove any whitespace around `=`. And drop those `;` and do one thing per line of code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$deployed = true
```

For assignment, remove the `$` and the spaces.

```
deployed=true
```

[Shellcheck.net](https://www.shellcheck.net/) is a great  web site for checking shell scripts for syntax errors, common mistakes, typos, and the like. Here's what it prints for your snippet, for example.

```
Line 1:
for i in "${list[@]}"
          ^-- SC2154: list is referenced but not assigned.

Line 3:
        if [ $i = "web.war" ] ; then
             ^-- SC2086: Double quote to prevent globbing and word splitting.

Line 4:
        $deployed = true; echo "Deployed!!!!!";
         ^-- SC1066: Don't use $ on the left side of assignments.
                  ^-- SC1068: Don't put spaces around the = in assignments.
```

Comment: Also to add, shellcheck is available on github & can also be installed via package managers on many linux distros. Plus, plugins are available for major editor programs.